# Raphael repeat background pattern

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I would like to have a repeated pattern of squares (a little like a blueprint) as a background to the entire SVG element.  I am using Raphael.  How can I accomplish this?

I want to do this with SVG rather than images as I pan / zoom the SVG using `SetViewBox` and I would like the background to scale appropriately too.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to render those squares the usual way, via `paper.rect()`. Might be expensive, though, and would take some maintenance if the canvas can grow in size.

The other option is to do a patterned fill, `paper.rect(0,0,100,100).attr({fill: "url(images/pattern.png)"});` (see [this tutorial](http://cancerbero.vacau.com/raphaeltut/)), which should automatically repeat the image it is given. I haven't done that myself, though, so I'm not really sure how the pattern is scaled when you do `SetViewBox()`.